# Xml errors thrown via Ws-fed authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, wif, ws-federation

I'm seeing the following error occur in the logs of a WIF-based reliant-party application that I work on and can't re-create the issue:

```
CData elements not valid at top level of an XML document. Line 1, position 3.
Stack Trace: at   System.Xml.XmlExceptionHelper.ThrowXmlException(XmlDictionaryReader reader, XmlException exception)
at System.Xml.XmlUTF8TextReader.Read()
at   System.Xml.XmlBaseReader.MoveToContent()
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSFederation.WSFederationSerializer..ctor(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.CreateSerializerForResultXml(String resultXml)
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.GetXmlTokenFromMessage(SignInResponseMessage message)
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.GetSecurityToken(SignInResponseMessage message)
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.SignInWithResponseMessage(HttpRequest request)
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs args)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Reading into possible issues [this Technet article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/uk/sharepoint2010programming/thread/00bb20a1-0e7f-4c3e-a1d5-9b8b08462bab) led me to think the problem was in the wresult parameter that is POSTed back to the RP from the STS but I can't see how that is being sent back incorrectly unless it's being tampered with and that seems unlikely due to the volume of issues.

If anyone can confirm what causes this type of error and how it may occur, it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever get a resolution on this? I'm having the same issue. Works in the Dev environment, not in the test environment.

Answer (score 1):

This error may occur as the content of the xml containing some "html tags" (such as 
, ,...) or some special character like "", "/", ...that could break the Xml schema. 
You should encode any html content before adding them to the Xml.

Updated:
Maybe you config the binding in web.config of WCF is transferMode=STREAMED. Just remove that. That may be the problem at least for me.

Comment: The XML is automatically generated by WIF, i'll have a look into whether any user-content being passed in the contained claims may contain special characters is not being encoded but AFAIK the encoding of that is out of my control

Answer (score 1):

had this happen to me. Changed the transfermode from Streamed to Buffered.

Comment: My is because this answer helped me. The service had a different transferMode but the client project didn't create the required binding correctly. I place this comment to help other people with the same issue.